# jQuery Cycle Flash Animation Issue

Tags: jquery, flash, animation, hide, cycle

I'm trying to [cycle](http://jquery.malsup.com/cycle/) Flash embedded videos and they behave strangely (they disappear AFTER parent div, not at the same time in addition they show up too fast and are being mixed with the next slide).

Here's an example (the issue is easy to see after clicking "3" while Flash content is visible):

http://soverflow.webuda.com/

I've been trying this solution (changing show and hide to visibility):

http://dev.kafol.net/2011/04/jquery-cycle-flash-swf-file-reloads.html

With no luck.

That's only one file so feel free to copy the source and play on your own.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If your content is solely flash. Why not make the sliding effect in flash too? I don't think the fading animation would work for the embedded flash object.

If you still want to use the cycle plugin. The I think you can write your one transition function for the fxFn Option. Use an overlay layer that goes from 0 - 1 Opacity then hide it when the transition is done.

Comment: Thanks for your response, what do you mean by "sliding effect in flash"?